# Sqlite Like Function in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sqlite

```
SELECT count(*) from BOOKS where BOOKS.TAG_ID like '%,1,%'
```

I wanna Execute this query in Objective-C.

```
 const char *sql = "Select count(*) from Documents WHERE DocumentTag LIKE '%i,?,%i'";
 sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
 NSString *bindParam = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", tagId];
if(sqlite3_bind_int(sqlStatement, 1, tagId)!= SQLITE_OK){
    NSLog(@"Problem binding search text param.");
}
else if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqlite3_bind_int(sqlStatement, 1, sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement, 0));
    if(sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW)
    taskCount=sqlite3_column_int(sqlStatement,0);
    sqlite3_reset(sqlStatement);
    sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);

}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are experiencing with this code? Some error occurs? Please add some more specific terms of the question you are asking. Thanks.

Comment: i dont know what you are expecting, if you want to get rows which contains DocumentTag of your text, then call like               const char *sql = "Select * from Documents WHERE DocumentTag LIKE ?";   and bind text using:     sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1,[@"your text" UTF8String], -1, NULL);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter markers are not recognized inside string literals (otherwise, it would not be possible to use `?` characters in strings).

You have to construct your `LIKE` pattern from three strings, your parameter and a prefix and a suffix:

```
const char *sql = "Select count(*) from Documents"
                  " WHERE DocumentTag LIKE '%i,' || ? || ',%i'";
```